# jQuery :checked not working with initial (HTML attribute) radio input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please inspect the following Console output, note that the 1st input has checked attribute and is selected:

[image]

You can see I have 2 radio `input`s, 1 is `checked`, however neither selector nor `prop` nor `is` works for it. The code works correctly if I manually click on one of the radio. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    Type:
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default active">
            <input type="radio" name="generator-type" id="opt-type-passphrase" value="0" autocomplete="off" checked>
            Passphrase
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="generator-type" id="opt-type-password" value="1" autocomplete="off">
            Password
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is the code not working when the page loads when I haven't clicked any radio? Is there a way to fix it?

**EDIT**: Found the problem, I have this code in the page load:

```
        $("input[name='generator-type'][value=" + this.Options.Type + "]").prop("checked", "");
```

The correct solution is using:

```
.prop("checked", true)
```

But can anyone please explain how it work? Why is there the `checked` attribute, but `prop` function is still false?

Comment: @HectorBarbossa Thank you, I found the source of problem, but still not understand how `prop` and `is` work yet. Could you explain it?

Comment: Your question regarding how it works is covered in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/). One key aspect to grasp: The HTML attribute only sets the *initial* value of the property. If it is changed via code or user interaction, the HTML doesn't change, but the property does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check like this

```
$( ... ).is(':checked')
```

Why? Because the jquery `is` method accepts a css selector which it uses to filter the currently matched elements.

Thus `temp.is('checked')` will only be true if the `temp` elements have the `checked` tag. In your case they have the `input` tag so do not match.

Using `:checked` matches on the css pseudo selector for whether the current element is checked or not. This is what you want.

Knowing this, you could also use `$( ... ).is('[checked]')`, which will return true if the matched elements have the `checked` attribute. That's probably what you were trying to do originally. Though, the conventional way is to use `:checked`.

Comment: Good catch. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

Try `.is(':checked')` instead of `.is('checked')`. Please check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HectorBarbossa/k2Lkyj0m/).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a colon in the is-checked code:

```
temp.is(":checked")
```

instead of

```
temp.is("checked")
```

Comment: How is this different from the existing answer?